# How to choose $f\in C^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support and takes value 1 on connected compact set?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $0< \delta < \pi$.

**My questions**:

> (1) How to construct(choose/method) $f\in C^{2}(\mathbb R)$(= First two [derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) ($f' \ \text{and}  \ f''$) of $f$ on $\mathbb R$ exists and are continuous on $\mathbb R$) which satisfies the  following property:
>   $$ f (x)=\begin{cases}
> 1 & \text{if}  \ x\in [-\pi + \delta, \pi -\delta ]\\
> 0, & \text {if} \  |x|> \pi.
> \end {cases}$$
>   (In other-words, we need to choose $f$ with two continuous derivatives and has compact support and takes value 1 on connected compact set. )

(2)How to construct(choose/method) $f\in C^{3}(\mathbb R)$(= First three derivative ($f', f'' \ \text{and}  \ f'''$) of $f$ on $\mathbb R$ exists and are continuous on $\mathbb R$) which satisfies the  following property:
$$ f (x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}  \ x\in [-\pi + \delta, \pi -\delta ]\\
0, & \text {if} \  |x|> \pi.
\end {cases}$$

(3) Can we expect to generalize this idea; I mean, can we choose $f\in C^{n}(\mathbb R)$ with a above properties ?

Thanks;

Comment: the key words in your searches is *bump function*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are standard. Actually you can make $f$ a $C^\infty$ function. Let

$g_1(x)= e^{-1/x}$

when $x>0$ and is zero when $x\leq 0$. This is a smooth function. Then

$g_2(x) = g_1(x)g_1(1-x)$

is a smooth function with support in $[0,1]$. Let

$g_3(x) = \int_{-1}^x g_2(s)ds$.

Then $g_3(x)$ is zero when $x<0$ and is constant when $x>1$. Let

$g_4(x) = g_3(x) g_3(3-x)$.

Then $g_4(x)$ is zero when $x<0$ and $x>3$, and is constant when $1\leq x\leq 2$. Finally let $f$ to be a suitable translation of $g_4$. If you want some pictures, you can found this in Hirsch's "differential topology".

The most general statement is the following: let $K_1$, $K_2$ be any disjoint closed sets in $\mathbb R^n$, then there is a smooth function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that

$$f^{-1}(0) = K_1,\ \ \ \ f^{-1}(1) = K_2$$

Comment: thanks a lot;if possible, please, can you give me reference for the last general statement you made for disjoint closed sets, (really, I find it is very attractive and I want to learn the proof for the general one);once again thanks a lot;-\).

Comment: @DivyangBhimani: The statement is actually a bit more general. It applies to smooth manifolds in general and the proof uses the partition of unity. The last statement appears in Ex2.14 of John M. Lee's "Introduction to smooth manifolds" (which can be proved using Theorem 2.29)

Answer (score 1):

You can use piecewise polynomials (splines). The only real problem is to decide what function to use in the "ramp" regions $-\pi < x <-\pi+\delta$ and $\pi - \delta < x <\pi$. For the $C^2$ case, let $f$ be a polynomial of degree 5. It will therefore have 6 coefficients, which we can determine from the following six equations 
$$
f(\pi - \delta)  = 1  \quad ; \quad 
f'(\pi - \delta) = 0  \quad ; \quad 
f''(\pi - \delta) = 0
$$
$$
f(\pi)  = 0  \quad ; \quad 
f'(\pi) = 0  \quad ; \quad 
f''(\pi) = 0
$$
If you read about Hermite interpolation (like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation), for example), or Bezier curves, you can actually write down an explicit formula for the $f$ satisfying these constraints, rather than solving the system of equations. For example, the Bezier-Bernstein polynomial
$$
f(x) = 10x^3(1-x)^2 + 5x^4(1-x) + x^5
$$
has the properties
$$
f(0)  = 0  \quad ; \quad 
f'(0) = 0  \quad ; \quad 
f''(0) = 0
$$
$$
f(1)  = 1  \quad ; \quad 
f'(1) = 0  \quad ; \quad 
f''(1) = 0
$$
and you can shift/scale it to suit your needs.

To make a piecewise function that's $C^n$, you will need to use polynomials of degree $2n-1$.